# Navbar doesn't work in my published site

Tags: php, html, laravel

[Published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0e63.jpg)

[Unpublished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyWgF.jpg)

My Navbar went missing i use Laravel and the function blade
Bootstrap is working seeing that the Jumbotron is activated

Can someone help?

Here is the navigation Code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>@yield('title')</title>

         <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
         <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

         <!-- Sweet Alert Css -->
         <link href="plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />

         <!-- Design Css -->
         <link href="plugins/pagecss/front_master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     </head>
     <body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
         <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
          <img id = "brnd" style="float:left;margin-top: 0.7em;margin-right: 1em;" alt="Brand" src="../images/index.jpg">               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">i-Kasal</a>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="#"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
               <li><div class="fb-share-button" data-
href="https://ikasal.uphero.com" data-layout="button_count" data-
size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a
class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank"
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
u=https%3A%2F%2Fikasal.uphero.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse"><button
id = "sharebtn" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Share 
@Facebook</button></a></div></li>
             </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li class = "@yield('Signup')"><a href="/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li class = "@yield('Login')"><a href="/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
       </nav>

       <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
       <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
       <script src="plugins/tether-master/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
       <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Jquery Validation Plugin Css -->
       <script src="plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

       <!-- Sweet Alert Plugin Js -->
       <script src="plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

       @yield('body')
   </body>
 </html>
```

And here is the welcome page code

```
 @extends('layout.main.front_master')

 @section('title','iKasal')

 @section('body')

 <!-- Design Css -->
 <link href="../../../plugins/pagecss/welcome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

         <div class="jumbotron" style = "padding-top:100px;">
           <div class="container">
             <h1 style="font-size:200px;">i-Kasal</h1>
             <p style="font-size:80px;">Welcome to iKasal</p>
             <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" 
             style="font-size:50px;width: 25%">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
 @endsection
```

Comment: which version use laravel ?

Comment: i used 5.4 if im correct

Comment: please all css and js check it is loaded perfectly or not use '<link href="{{ asset('public/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >' for **css** and '<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/custom.js') }}"></script>' for **js**

Comment: uhmm still nothing happens i really dont know why i check all the links and scripts and there are no errors in the consoles

Comment: because of for navigation loading need necessary js and css if proper js and css not found it is not work properly

Comment: Thanks for your help :D It seems the problem is the bootstrap!.
I used the alpha 4 and when i tried to change the script to the bootstrap 3 it was fixed Thanks again!

Comment: if you have found a solution. Please answer your own question so users in the future can get help from this question.